# How can I print empty space for every list element which is equal to zero without changing the original list?

Tags: python, list, printing, formatting, time-complexity

So I am trying to make a numerical tic tac toe game, where you input numbers and you win if it adds up to 15 horizontally/vertically/diagonally

at first, I just put zeros into an empty list.
But eventually, I am gonna replace the zeros with numbers greater than zero.

I want to print the tic tac toe in this format:

> ```
>         0   1   2  
>      0    |   |   
>        -----------
>      1    |   |   
>        -----------
>      2    |   |
> ```

so I used this code -

```
print("    0   1   2 ")
        for row in range(self.size):
            print(" {0}  {1} | {2} | {3}  ".format(row, self.board[row][0], self.board[row][1], self.board[row][2]))
            if row < 2:
                print('   -----------')
```

but it prints out

```
        0   1   2  
     0  0 | 0 | 0 
       -----------
     1  0 | 0 | 0 
       -----------
     2  0 | 0 | 0
```

I want to print empty space where there is zero in the list (without changing the actual list)
so if the element in the list is greater than 0 then we print it else we print empty space

One solution to the problem is this:

```
print("    0   1   2 ")
            for row in range(self.size):
                print(" {0}  {1} | {2} | {3}  ".format(row, self.board[row][0] if self.board[row][0]> 0 else ' ', self.board[row][1] if self.board[row][1]> 0 else ' ', self.board[row][2] if self.board[row][2]> 0 else ' '))
                if row < 2:
                    print('   -----------')
```

But in this case, the line has more than 120 characters which is not acceptable.
I also do not want to use a for loop within another for loop because that will only increase the complexity and run time

what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

i tried to doodle it, its not pythonic yet but output looks good

```
board = [[0,0,2],[0,1,0],[0,7,0]]

print('    0   |   1   |   2')
print('---------------------')

rowCount = 0
for eachRow in board:
    temp = "  |  ".join(str(x) for x in eachRow)
    temp = temp.replace("0", " " )
    print(str(rowCount)  + ' |   ' + temp)
    print('---------------------')
    rowCount = rowCount + 1
```

[image]

Comment: also, i had built a TTT last year. If you'd like to see the code - FYI - https://github.com/rathiankush123/games

Comment: Thanks this works but it still uses a for loop inside another for loop tho, kinda don't wanna increase the complexity here

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use list comprehension to reduce number of characters, but it unfortunately does not help with the complexity reduction. Please keep in mind that this is just used as an example.

```
board = np.zeros((3,3))


print("    0   1   2 ")
for row in range(3):
    a = [board[row][i] if board[row][i] else "" for i in range(3)]
    print(" {0}  {1} | {2} | {3}  ".format(row, a[0], a[1], a[2] ))
    if row < 2:
        print('   -----------')
```